# Proof that $ \langle x \rangle = \{rx + nx \mid r \in R, n \in \mathbb Z\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help in constructing a proof for this:

Let M be an R-Module and $x\in M$. Then the submodule generated by x is given by
$$\langle x \rangle = \{rx + nx \mid r \in R, n \in \mathbb Z\}.$$

Comment: The proof is straight forward, no special ideas are necessary. What have you tried? Please share your thoughts. It might be also good for you to repeat the definitions.

Comment: I get that it's straightforward but I'm quite unsure how to construct the proof.

Comment: @user175953 What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you understand the definition of the submodule generated by a subset. By definition, $\langle x\rangle$ is the smallest submodule containing $x$. So you will need to check two things:

1. The set $\langle x \rangle = \{rx + nx \mid r \in R, n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is indeed a submodule containing $x$.
2. If $M$ is a submodule containing $x$, use the module axiom to show that $\langle x \rangle = \{rx + nx \mid r \in R, n \in \mathbb Z\}$ lies inside $M$.
   Both should be straightforward definition tracking and I shall leave it to you as an exercise.